# How can i understand the concept of ‘user script directory’?

Tags: python

I'm reading [PEP370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/#id22),it introduces a concept of 'user script directory' with words below:

> A directory for binaries and scripts. It's shared across Python versions and the destination directory for scripts.

How to understand such words(especially the second sentence)?

Comment: What.... Don't you understand?

Comment: No,i don't. I want some simple,concise words to describe it.I don't know how it can be shared by many Python versions and destination directory for scripts.

Comment: Some end-user systems call directories "folders".  Does that help?

Comment: I know the concept of directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEP370 describes a standard per-user directory to store installed packages (with tools such as `pip`). Before this existed, there was only the system-wide site-packages directory.

The phrase you quoted means that this directory (located in the user's `$HOME` in Unix, for example) is **unique** for all python versions, and the default target location for user-level package installations.

Note that, for real-life projects, [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) is usually the tool for localized package installations. It allows per-project (more restricted than per-system-user) site-packages directories.

Comment: For example Python2.7.2 and Python3.5.2, can they coexist in the directory?